# Gnome settings changes don't stick

Tags: settings

After some recent update to Ubuntu 20.04, some settings in the Gnome Settings app have not been restored after waking up. This is on a laptop. I use Settings to set the external mouse to natural scrolling direction and sound output to the built-in audio. After opening the laptop lid, those changes are lost, and the natural scrolling direction is off and the output sound device is different (I have this Lenovo Yoga L13 connected to a dock and four sound devices are shown. The one that waking the laptop gets the sound device set to is a digital output device that I'm not even familiar with).

I can't find out where the Settings values are stored, so I haven't been able to check if there's a permission problem. I don't see any similar reports to this, here are in the Internet at large. I suspect this is specific to my computer, but I don't know what to check next.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Having the same thing recently. Both natural scrolling and a tweak I have in gnome-tweaks to set caps lock as an additional backspace key both get reset. I think mine is related to the external USB-C dongle I use to connect peripherals. I think when I plug it in or out, these two settings reset. Pretty annoying and only started recently. I keep hoping somebody will figure it out and fix it.

Comment: Same thing, I have two machines and a kvm switch and everytime I switch I need to:
  - Fix my mouse sensitivity in Settings
  - Swap Caps Lock and Escape in Tweaks

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a few bugs about this, though none that is getting much action:

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1505
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/issues/555
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1899509
- https://github.com/pop-os/gnome-control-center/issues/120
- https://www.reddit.com/r/System76/comments/j3ozik/pop_2004_updates_from_today_break_mouse_settings/

Looks like tomorrow will be a month that we've all been dealing with this.

:(